# How to use camera calibration with ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: calibration, ubuntu, opencv2, ubuntu-trusty, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo. I try to run lsd_slam using image list. It requires a calibration file. So, I try to create a calibration file using `rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 image:=/my_camera/image camera:=/my_camera`  command in ubuntu terminal.

It throws an error :

```
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/camera_calibration/cameracalibrator.py", line 47, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223796/how-to-use-camera-calibration-with-ubuntu-14.04?/) by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2016-01-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dfornas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25543/dfornas/) on 2016-01-12**:
This is a problem caused by the migration of some non-free features from OpenCV to external packages. I cannot recall what I did exactly to solve this but you should check in the OpenCV forums. It happened to me with a SURF feature detector.

**Comment by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on 2016-01-13**:
I reinstall opencv includes c++, python. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a reasonably up-to-date version of 14.04 with Indigo, and I can start the camera calibration node without issue.

This is either an issue with a very recent version of camera calibration, or an issue with your system.

The version of opencv that is normally used by ROS is Ubuntu's default version, and it does not ship with the "nonfree" module, and the accompanying python wrapper shouldn't be trying to load it.

Does trying to load the OpenCV python wrapper by itself work? Try:

```
python -c 'import cv2'
```

Have you done anything to modify your version of OpenCV, or attempted to install OpenCV3? Did you do an installation of OpenCV from source, in addition to the version of OpenCV that already comes with ROS?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on 2016-01-13**:
I reinstall opencv c++, pyhton. And it works.